# Can I travel to Schengen countries with only an Italian Carta di Identità?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, europe, italy

I'm living in Milan and I have to go to Berlin this October, but my Permesso di Soggiorno or permit to stay in Italy will expire in September.

Can I travel to Germany with just my Carta di Identità? Will there be a problem at Immigration if I can't show a Permesso di Soggiorno?

Some friends think I only need the Carta di Identità because the Permesso di Soggiorno is only for Italy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are a European citizen, *[yes](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_d%27identit%C3%A0_italiana_(cartacea)#Con_validit.C3.A0_per_l.27espatrio)* - otherwise, *no* - and since you mentioned you hold a *Permesso Di Soggiorno* I believe you are not a European citizen.

To make sure, check if you have this sentence on the cover page:

> NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO.

Which translates to: *Not valid for travelling abroad.*

[image: Carta di Identità]

Comment: Note: It appears that Italy writes this notice on identity cards it issues to non-citizen residents. Identiy cards for _Italian citizens_ should not have this notation, and _are_ valid documentation for the holder's freedom of movement in the EEA/EU.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Hatef: so the answer is actually "no, and futhermore  the carta d'identità has no validity outside Italy whether or not you bring your permesso di soggiorno."  The traveler needs the permesso di soggiorno plus a passport.

Comment: @HenningMakholm you are absolutely right; I updated my answer. :)

Comment: @phoog exactly - your statement applies to all non EU citizens with a residence permit card.

Comment: Does Italy issue this card to non-Italian EU citizens? If so, don't those cards have the same notation?  Under EU law a "national ID card" allowing freedom of movement is to be issued by the country of nationality because, for example, Italy is not competent to say that someone is, for example, an Estonian citizen.

Comment: @phoog I'm not aware of that, but anyway for EU citizens simply holding a passport or an ID from their home country should suffice as a travelling document.

Comment: @phoog: I found [this document](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meetdocs/2009_2014/documents/peti/cm/829/829524/829524en.pdf), indicating that at least in 2010 Italy did issue cards with "non valida per l'espatrio" to non-Italian EU citizens -- but the EU Commission was of the opinion that those cards could _nevertheless_ be used to prove the holder's right of freedom of movement.

Comment: @HenningMakholm mine was issued in 2015 with that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just got mine today and it has NON VALIDA PER L'ESPATRIO. written at the back. I had to do this because I lost my permisso sorgiorno and have already applied for a replacement one. so Besically its a no use with regards to traveling outside Italy