# Can I travel to Spain with expired passport (Philippines) but with only Permesso di Soggiorno and Carta D'identità Italiana?

Tags: schengen

I have my Philippine passport that will expire this July (2021) and I'm still waiting for my Permesso di Soggiorno to be released anytime sooner.

Comment: It is not yet July 2021, you have time to renew the passport before it expires. Or do you intent to travel before July 2021 and are you worried about traveling with less than 3 or 6 months left on your passport?

Comment: @Willeke i dont think i can renew my passport this year because when i checked the embassy in Rome online and tried to book an appointment, i found that all months are booked til December, so i don't think that there's a posssiblity for me to renew it on time

Comment: @Willeke so im just like hoping and looking for answers, if i can travel outside Italy like i mentioned Spain with expired passport but only with Permesso di Soggiorno and Carta D'identitá Italiana

Comment: @Willeke don't intent to travel before July 2021 but anytime this year also im worried if there will be some troubles or problems if I tried to travel with the specific documents I have at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Please remember, Carta D’identità is (more or less) a symbolic ID card and you can’t travel with it or use it as an ID outside Italy (this should also be stated on the [back](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/96078/9679) of the card).

Furthermore, [according to the rules](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-nationals/index_en.htm), as a non-EU you **always** need to carry a valid passport. Even though, documents are not frequently checked between Schengen flights, you should always have it on you or if not you must have a valid justification or replacement.

One solution, as suggested by @Willeke is to contact the embassy and request for an emergency paperwork.

Comment: To make the point stronger, if you do not have a passport, or papers from your embassy, do not travel outside the country you are a resident. Your Italian card is no replacement for a passport. Not being checked is no excuse.

Comment: Nitpick: in Spain, the Italian ID card is accepted by the Guardia Civil database that we were required to update when checking in guests to hostels and other lodging.

Comment: @WGroleau I think, it could be fine just to show your name or something in that range but officially it doesn't have much power (so, it can't be used in the airports). And to be clear, this is the ID that is issued to non-EU citizens. As an Italian, you can use your Carta D’identità as an official ID.

Comment: @WGroleau: An ID card is acceptable for travel in the EU if you are a EU, EEA or CH citizen. If you are not you will need to carry your passport.

Comment: OK, it wasn’t clear that a non-citizen card was meant.  Spain also accepts the Spanish non-citizen’s NIE for the lodging DB and all sorts of other things, but I never tried to use mine at an airport.